# How to disable internal mic if external headset is connected?

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

I have a small problem with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, every time I connect my headset via Bluetooth, the default mic is the internal one, this is not happening with the sound. So I have to manually switch the mic from the internal to the external all the time. Do you know how can I disable the internal mic if an external one is connected? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the man page for amixer:

```
$ man amixer
```

There are some commands in there to select/activate the devices.

For example I use this to turn off my microphone:

```
$ amixer set Capture nocap
```

Hope that points you in the right direction!